# A.CLASS:LINK only works for 1st element in Firefox

Tags: css, class, firefox, hyperlink

For my navigation, I have set a class for 3 links as :link, and :hover. In Firefox (3.6.28) only the first link will pick up the specs I've set (as :link,) but in Safari (4.1.3) they all show up fine. However, the :hover class specs will show up fine in both browsers.

Seems like the simplest problem but I have no idea why this is like this. They are nested in a table, and I isolated them outside the table, but still no difference. I've searched on Stack and Google for answers but could not find anything relative.

```
A.ANAV:LINK {color:#ac1700; font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size:20px; letter-spacing:; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #006924; text-decoration:none;}
A.ANAV:HOVER    {color:#ac1700; font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif; font-size:20px; letter-spacing:; font-weight:bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000000; text-decoration:none;}

<a href="index.php" class="ANAV">HOME</a>
<a href="services.php" class="ANAV">SERVICES</a>
<a href="photos.php" class="ANAV">PHOTOS</a>
```

Here's the site for reference - [The Weed Guys](http://www.theweedguys.com/)

Comment: Stack won't let me officially answer my own question...

Comment: I just ran into a friend who pointed out it was **probably** a bug in Firefox because it's a really old version, but I took the ":link" suffix off of the class, and it worked fine. (also added a duplicate ":visited" class as well, worked fine.)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for answering your own question and posting it :)

It's probably not a terrible idea to do something like `a, a:link {color:red}` then you cover all your bases.

Answer (score 0):

`:link` only matches unvisited links.  Have you visited services.php and photos.php in your Firefox?

If you want to match all links, you have to style `:visited` as well.